# Select options from parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a @miniature model. Miniatures have_many Manufacturers via @minilines
I have a @line model. Lines belong_to Manufacturer.

When you want to add a @miniature to a @Line you click on the following link.

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add'.html_safe, new_miniline_path(:miniature_id => @miniature) %>
```

The form you then see is as follows

```
<%= form_for(@miniline) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :miniature_id, :value => @miniature.id %>

    <%= f.label :line_id, 'Select product line' %><br />
    <%= f.select :line_id, @lines, include_blank: true %>


  <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This works fine but what I want to do is make the options_for_select display only the @lines associated with the @manufacturer of the current @miniature.

I'm currently trying

```
<%= f.select :line_id, mfr_lines(@miniature), include_blank: true %>
```

and then defining it in a minilines_helper but I can't work out how to phrase it

```
module MinilinesHelper

    def mfr_lines(miniature)
        miniature.manufacturers.each do |manufacturer|
            manufacturer.lines

        end
    end

end
```

It wants to take each manufacturer and get their lines and then join them.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
<%= f.select :line, @lines, include_blank: true %>
```

Just don't use **:line_id** as a name, rails knows what to do if you name the related model here.

Comment: The form above is working fine with :line_id. I'm trying to filter the options_for_select as outlined below.